# tomcat configuring with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

whats the cause of this error while running tomcat 6.0 on eclipse ide helious:

Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Comment: I don't see any error log on your post.

Answer (score 4):

Just read the error message: Tomcat is already running.

Comment: If there's a 404 error, that means SOME server is running on 8080 and returned a 404.

Comment: If possible I would look for and terminate all running java processes and then try again.

Answer (score 3):

Or:

- you have tomcat running in your eclipse workspace (**solution**: stop the server in eclipse or the eclipse process from your task manager)
- your tomcat is running in the background as a service (**solution**: kill the tomcat process from your task manager and disable the windows service)
- the ports tomcat use are used by other programs running in the background (**solution**: kill the processes using these ports from your task manager)

Answer (score 1):

Some application is using the ports configured in Tomcat.

Either check the applications using these ports with netstat and kill them, or configure different ports for Tomcat.

Check if there's any Java Application Server running, they generally use these ports.

Sometimes when you run Tomcat from within Eclipse, you stop Tomcat from the Servers view, and it keeps running on the background. I've found that restarting Eclipse makes it stop for good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the tomcat server must not start from inside the Eclipse, it should start from the cmd screen by using the files startup.dat and shutdown by using the shutdown.dat file using their pathin the cmd like this:

D:\Apache-Software-Foundation\Tomcat-8.0\bin\startup.bat

D:\Apache-Software-Foundation\Tomcat-8.0\bin\shutdown.bat